# How can I allow one or more arguments for initializing a class?

Tags: python, class

If I want to create a class where each instance has to have at least one arguments but could have more. If it has none it should raise an exception. How can i achieve this?

Comment: use the `*args` magic: `def __init__(self, arg1, *args): ...`

Answer (score 3):

You could write your class like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, first, *rest):
        # do something with the args
```

This accepts the first argument as `first` and any additional arguments as a tuple, `rest`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by [kindall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29934950/356528) is the most pythonic way to do it:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, first, *rest):
        # do something with the args
```

It will raise a `TypeError` whenever you forget about the `first` argument. Here is how you would go about it if you wished to raise a custom exception:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if not args:
            raise MyCustomException()
        first_arg = args[0]
        ...
```